# How to implement .aidl file in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, printers

I am trying to use flutter to communicate with SunMi mobile printer. I want to invoke the printer using AIDL as one of the ways to communicate with the printer but i don't know how and where to place the AIDL files in flutter or is it even possible to use flutter in my case. I need to know if it is possible to communicate with the printer using its AIDL. I am opting to use flutter or android studio with java for my application.

Source of question : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49413#issue-554566892

i could not find the proper answer so posted the question here.

Comment: I don't know if you still need it, but I have done this and it is indeed possible, and the good news is that it's very easy.

You'll just have to write the android part that binds to the aidl. I can provide an answer with some code later for you if you still need it, and for people who might find this question eventually. I'm just nowhere near my computer at the moment.

Comment: @arvil that would be extremely greatful

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an AIDL file we're talking about, it would be safe to assume that this is an Android only feature.

To do this, like any other Android-specific `MethodChannel` implementation, you'll need to create a MethodCallHandler and/or an StreamHandler (depending if you want to do streams or just an command -> result approach), register it on the Main FlutterActivity, and call it from dart through MethodChannels.

**DISCLAIMER**

- The code below is not tested and might have some syntax errors, let me know if you find issues and I'll address them.
- I have combined everything in one file for brevity, you can move some parts of the code to separate files as you see fit.

**Creating the MethodCallHandler/StreamHandler**

Inside your `android/app/src/main/com/some/path` folder in your flutter app, create a new java file and implement `ServiceConnection`, `MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler` and/or `EventChannel.StreamHandler`:

```
public class PrinterPlugin implements MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler, EventChannel.StreamHandler, ServiceConnection {
   public static final CHANNEL = "com.some.path/printer";
   public static final EVENT_CHANNEL = "com.some.path/printer-events";

   private Context context;
   private IPrinterService printerService = null; // where IPrinterService would be the AIDL's name

   public EventChannel.EventSink eventSink = null;

   public PrinterPlugin(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        if (printerService == null) {
            // these strings should be in your documentation or you can find these values from the package manager
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.your.printer.service");
            intent.setPackage("com.whatever.aidl"); 
            context.bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        context.unbindService(this);
    }

    // streamhandler implementation
    @Override
    public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
        this.eventSink = events;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
         this.eventSink = null;
    }
    // /streamhandler implementation


    // methodcallhandler implementation
    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
      try {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "initialize": printerService.printerInit(); break;
            case "print-text": printerService.printText(call.argument("data")); break;
            // implement other aidl methods
        }
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
         result.error("", ex.getMessage(), null);
      }
    }
    // /methodcallhandler implementation

    // serviceConnection implementation
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        printerService = IPrinterService .Stub.asInterface(service);

        if (eventSink != null) {
            eventSink.success("Printer Connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        printerService = null;

        if (eventSink != null) {
            eventSink.success("Printer Disconnected");
        }
    }
    // /serviceConnection implementation
}
```

**Register the PrinterPlugin to the MainActivity as a MethodChannel and EventChannel**

Now that that's out of the way, you'll need to register this plugin on the `MainActivity`'s `configureFlutterEngine` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private PrinterPlugin printerPlugin;

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        Context context = getContext();
        printerPlugin = new PrinterPlugin(context);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), PrinterPlugin.CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler(printerPlugin);

        new EventChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), PrinterPlugin.EVENT_CHANNEL)
            .setStreamHandler(printerPlugin);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        this.printerPlugin.unbindService();
    }
}
```

**Call the methods from dart**

Now the last thing that you need to do is call these from dart.

```
const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('com.some.path/printer'); // should match the CHANNEL constant on the java side
const EventChannel _evntChannel = EventChannel('com.some.path/printer-events'); // should match the EVENT_CHANNEL constant on the java side

class PrinterPlugin {
   static Stream<dynamic> _printerStream = _eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream();
   Stream<String> status$;

   PrinterPlugin() {
      status$ = _printerStream;
   }

   static Future printText(String data) async {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('initialize');
      await _channel.invokeMethod('print-text', 'Foo Bar');
   }
}
```

Well, that was a lot of code - but that's basically how I did it. Just a `MethodCallHandler` with a `ServiceConnection` implementation.

You can go crazy with this implementation as well, like real-time printing progress, or getting streamed printer status, etc.

Let me know if it works for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your the printer uses a BT or USB interface (Sometimes even if the device has a built-in printer, they still use a USB interface via a ribbon cable), you can ditch the SDK of the vendor and use a flutter package for POS printing like [flutter_esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_esc_pos_utils).

To check which interface is being used, first install the above package and run this:

```
final profiles = await CapabilityProfile.getAvailableProfiles();
```

I have used this approach to print on the built in printer of self-ordering kiosk. Cuts down on the development time & makes your
app compatible with more hardware.